# HTML5 video duration issue

Tags: ios, html5-video

I'm developing a web aplication for iphone... I'm using smooth streaming and the results are working fine in a direct html5 video tag, but the problem is that this tag doesn't support duration and starttime modification...
Does anybody knows a player that could solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till today... 25/04/2012 there isn't something to solve this. The closest one can set a fake duration and start in another time, but the iOS player will always show the real time.